# Problem with Inheritance beetwen classes//java

Tags: java

I've been trying to use a constructor and functions from class Adding in class AddOwner (which inherits from class Adding).

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Adding extends JFrame {

    protected JFrame frame;

    Adding(){
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.setSize(300, 500);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);



        frame.setVisible(true);
    }


    class AddingTextField extends JTextField{
        protected JTextField nameField;
        String textFieldContent;

        AddingTextField(String textFieldContent) {
            nameField = new JTextField(textFieldContent);
            nameField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 50));
            nameField.setFont(new Font("MV Boli", Font.PLAIN, 35));
        }
    }



    class AddingDropList  <T> extends JComboBox{
        protected JComboBox dropListContent;
        AddingDropList(){
            dropListContent=new JComboBox<>();
            dropListContent.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,50));
            dropListContent.setFont(new Font("MV Boli",Font.PLAIN,35));
        }

        public void addContentToDropList(T content){
            dropListContent.addItem(content);
        }

        public void removeContentFromDropList(T content){
            dropListContent.removeItem(content);
        }
    }


}
```

class AddOwner:

```
public class AddOwner extends Adding{

    
    private AddingTextField name;
    private AddingTextField surname;
    private AddingTextField age;
    private AddingDropList gender;


    public AddOwner(){
        
        super();
 
        name=new AddingTextField("name");
        surname=new AddingTextField("surname");
        age =new AddingTextField("age");
        gender=new AddingDropList<String>();
        gender.addContentToDropList("Male");
        gender.addContentToDropList("Female");
        this.add(name);
        this.add(surname);
        this.add(age);
        this.add(gender);

        



    }
}
```

Unfortunately, frame poped up without added components. I decided to discard construtor from class Adding and use at least classes from Adding clas to created objects AddingTextField and AddingDropList.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Adding extends JFrame {


    public class AddingTextField extends JTextField{
        protected JTextField nameField;
        String textFieldContent;

        AddingTextField(String textFieldContent) {
            nameField = new JTextField(textFieldContent);
            nameField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 50));
            nameField.setFont(new Font("MV Boli", Font.PLAIN, 35));
        }
    }



    public class AddingDropList  <T> extends JComboBox{
        protected JComboBox dropListContent;
        AddingDropList(){
            dropListContent=new JComboBox<>();
            dropListContent.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,50));
            dropListContent.setFont(new Font("MV Boli",Font.PLAIN,35));
        }

        public void addContentToDropList(T content){
            dropListContent.addItem(content);
        }

        public void removeContentFromDropList(T content){
            dropListContent.removeItem(content);
        }
    }


}
```

Class AddOwner:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class AddOwner extends Adding {
    private JFrame frame;
    private AddingTextField name;
    private AddingTextField surname;
    private AddingTextField age;
    private AddingDropList gender;


    AddOwner(){

        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.setSize(300, 500);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        name=new AddingTextField("name");
        surname=new AddingTextField("surname");
        age =new AddingTextField("age");
        gender=new AddingDropList<String>();
        gender.addContentToDropList("Male");
        gender.addContentToDropList("Female");
        frame.add(name);
        frame.add(surname);
        frame.add(age);
        frame.add(gender);
        frame.setVisible(true);



    }
}
```

Now it's been adding components, but it looks like that
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AG4qQ.png)

Can anyone explain it to me, why it doesn't work?

Comment: I think you have a misunderstanding about inheritance! To stick with your first class, `public class Adding extends JFrame` means that `Adding` IS A `JFrame`!

Answer (score 0):

Give the Components you add specific sizes. Without them, they will all have minimum size (0 or very small).

Or use another LayoutManager that automatically adjusts its Components' sizes.